# error with switch cases...code not returning anything

Tags: java, barcode, zipcode

The assignment for the project that I am working on is for the user to be able to input a zip code and for the program to provide the bar code in the output. For example, the bar code for 95014 right now should be "|:|:::|:|:||::::::||:|::|". This is all based on a table I have that denotes what each number should be (shown in the case statements). This is the code I wrote for that portion:

```
public class Zipcode{

private String zipcode = "";
private String barcode = "";
private int zipnum = 0;

public Zipcode(int zip_number){
    zipnum = zip_number;
}

public void createBarcode(){
    while (zipnum > 0){
        switch (zipnum % 10)
        {
            case 0: 
                barcode = "||:::";
                break;
            case 1: 
                barcode = ":::||";
                break;
            case 2: 
                barcode = "::|:|";
                break;
            case 3: 
                barcode = "::||:";
                break;
            case 4: 
                barcode = ":|::|";
                break;
            case 5: 
                barcode = ":|:|:";
                break;
            case 6: 
                barcode = ":||::";
                break;
            case 7: 
                barcode = "|:::|";
                break;
            case 8: 
                barcode = "|::|:";
                break;
            case 9: 
                barcode = "|:|::";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        barcode += barcode;
        zipnum = zipnum / 10;
    }
}

public String getBarcode(){
    return barcode;
    }
}
```

However, when my tester class calls this class after the user inputs a zip code, nothing comes up as the result. Please help! Why isn't anything being returned? I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You never call `#createBarcode`

Comment: It appears that `barcode` is declared as `""` and if you never call `createBarcode()` then you'll never print anything

Comment: Also, if every time you call `barcode = whatever` you'll never get more than 5 characters stored in `barcode`

Comment: @Rogue I have a tester class that calls getBarcode()

Comment: @jaynepants but what good will that do, if `#createBarcode` is never called? `#getBarcode` just returns the field value, it doesn't initialize anything

Comment: You also have a more subtle problem.  The loop should execute exactly 5 times regardless of the input. With your current code, a Puerto Rico Zip code such as 00901 would only output 3 digits of barcode, not the full 5 with two leading zeroes.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that you re-assign barcode variable in each switch-case block and append itself again in the end.

You can do it with a temporary variable inside the method:

```
public void createBarcode(){
    String tempBarcode = "";
    ...
        case 0:
            tempBarcode = "||:::";
            break;
    ....
    barcode += tempBarcode;
```

But I think the cleanest solution would be to use it as an utility method without any class variable dependencies:

```
public static String calculateBarcode(int zipNumber) {
    StringBuilder barcode = new StringBuilder();
    while (zipNumber > 0) {
        switch (zipNumber % 10) {
            case 0:
                barcode.append("||:::");
                break;
            case 1:
                barcode.append(":::||");
                break;
            ...
            ...
            default:
                break;
        }
        zipNumber = zipNumber / 10;
    }
    return barcode.toString();
}
```

Simple testcase:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(ZipcodeUtil.calculateBarcode(95014));
    /* Output: :|::|:::||||::::|:|:|:|:: */
}
```

Comment: Or, easier, `barCode += "||:::";` in the switch case.

Comment: Also: better to return a `String` from `createBarcode`. Using a member variable makes things messier.

Comment: Agreed. I was trying to point out that you don't want to re-assign barcode variable with a new partial value.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't appending the zip value on every iteration correctly. The value is getting lost as you are overriding the value here on this step

```
   ...
        case 0: 
                barcode = "||:::";
                break;
   ...
```

Instead use a temporary variable to store the current iterations zip code value

```
public class Zipcode {

    private String zipcode = "";
    private String barcode = "";
    private int zipnum = 0;

    public Zipcode(int zip_number) {
        zipnum = zip_number;
    }

    public void createBarcode() {
        String temp_barcode = "";
        while (zipnum > 0) {
            System.out.println(zipnum % 10);
            switch (zipnum % 10) {
            case 0:
                temp_barcode = "||:::";
                System.out.println(0);
                break;
            case 1:
                temp_barcode = ":::||";
                System.out.println(1);
                break;
            case 2:
                temp_barcode = "::|:|";
                System.out.println(2);
                break;
            case 3:
                temp_barcode = "::||:";
                System.out.println(3);
                break;
            case 4:
                temp_barcode = ":|::|";
                System.out.println(4);
                break;
            case 5:
                temp_barcode = ":|:|:";
                System.out.println(5);
                break;
            case 6:
                temp_barcode = ":||::";
                System.out.println(6);
                break;
            case 7:
                temp_barcode = "|:::|";
                System.out.println(7);
                break;
            case 8:
                temp_barcode = "|::|:";
                System.out.println(8);
                break;
            case 9:
                temp_barcode = "|:|::";
                System.out.println(9);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            barcode += temp_barcode;
            System.out.println(barcode);
            zipnum = zipnum / 10;
        }
    }

    public String getBarcode() {
        return barcode;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Zipcode z = new Zipcode(95014);
        z.createBarcode();
        System.out.println(z.getBarcode()); // output: :|::|:::||||::::|:|:|:|::
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `barcode` this way

```
        case 0: 
            barcode += "||:::";
            break;
        case 1: 
            barcode += ":::||";
            break;
        case 2: 
            barcode += "::|:|";
            break;
        case 3: 
            .....
            .....
            .....
```

and remove this line

```
        barcode += barcode;
```

This will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your barcode variable overwrite in your code so add local variable in createBarcode method. try this:

```
public class Zipcode{

private String zipcode = "";
private String barcode = "";
private int zipnum = 0;

public static void main(String[] a){
    Zipcode z = new Zipcode(1568);
    System.out.println(z.zipnum);
    z.createBarcode();
    System.out.println(z.zipnum);
    System.out.println(z.getBarcode());
}

public Zipcode(int zip_number){
    zipnum = zip_number;
}

public void createBarcode(){
    while (zipnum > 0){
        String barcode;
        switch (zipnum % 10)
        {
            case 0:
                barcode = "||:::";
                break;
            case 1:
                barcode = ":::||";
                break;
            case 2:
                barcode = "::|:|";
                break;
            case 3:
                barcode = "::||:";
                break;
            case 4:
                barcode = ":|::|";
                break;
            case 5:
                barcode = ":|:|:";
                break;
            case 6:
                barcode = ":||::";
                break;
            case 7:
                barcode = "|:::|";
                break;
            case 8:
                barcode = "|::|:";
                break;
            case 9:
                barcode = "|:|::";
                break;
            default:
                barcode = "";
                break;
        }
        this.barcode += barcode;
        zipnum = zipnum / 10;
    }
}

public String getBarcode(){
    return barcode;
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

First create a Zipcode instance, Zipcode code = Zipcode(9)

Then call createBarcode() for that instance, so in my case code.createBarcode()

Then you can print out the getBarcode() method.

REMEMBER, getBarcode() only returns a String with the barcode but it does not print it out. You must use print to print it out.

EXAMPLE: System.out.println(code.getBarcode())